# How to bake admin (prefixed) code with CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, admin, crud, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-bake

Can anyone tell me what is the official way to create CRUD for admin back-end?

In CakePHP 2 the baked code was extended with 'admin_' before the function names and for the view files.
In CakePHP it seems I can't find any direct information on how it's done anymore. The bake console doesn't ask for admin anymore.
In this topic: https://github.com/cakephp/bake/issues/28 I see that they mention to use the --prefix extension but then the controller is placed in a separate /Admin folder while the CRUD functions keep having their normal name. And in some parts of the cookbook () I still see they mention functions like admin_view.

So can anyone tell me what is the official 'Cake'-way to do this from 3.2 on?

Comment: And in some parts of the cookbook: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts

Answer (score 10):

If you want to create Controller using cake bake. You can do this with below command:

```
bin/cake bake controller --prefix admin users
```

For view:

```
bin/cake bake template --prefix admin users
```

> It creates the admin folder in the template directory, Then it creates the folder for users, then it includes the files. for admin prefix folder structure like `template/admin/users/index.ctp`

[See official cookbook documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html)

Also In your config/routes.php add this:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
    // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
    // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how things work now in CakePHP 3, prefixed methods are gone, prefixes now do generate separate controllers in sub-namespaces, for smaller/simpler controllers, and for proper separation, not only on controller level, but also on template level, where the templates are expected to be placed in separate folders accordingly.

The `admin_view` example you are referring to is just an example that should show how to manually set a custom layout for specific actions, it has nothing to do with prefix routing.

So, if you want to use prefix routing, then the "official" way is to use the `--prefix` option.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Prefix Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)**
- **[Cookbook > Bake Console > Code Generation with Bake](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html)**

Comment: Thanks. I understand. However I have a problem with the bake templates used for the admin. I have put a controller bake file in src/Template/Bake/Controller/Admin/controller.ctp but baking a controller with --prefix admin doesn't use that file. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can anyone tell me where/how to save the new bake template for prefix routing? When I bake a controller with --prefix Admin it creates the Controller/Admin/controller.php file from the Template/Bake/Controller/controller.php file instead of from the Template/Bake/Controller/Admin/controller.php file. But I want different code generated in the main controller and in the Admin/controller.

Comment: @Lucky Please open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the bake command to bake all prefix controller and templates for users table

```
cake bake all users --prefix admin
```

And here is the route code to make it working:-

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
        // Because you are in the admin scope,
        // you do not need to include the /admin prefix
        // or the admin route element.
        $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
        $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
        // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
    //$routes->connect('/admin', ['controller' => 'Order', 'action' => 'index']); // call other controller like this
        // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
        $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
    });
```

This will work for me hope it will work for you :)